# Interpretation of stable Hom in Nakayama algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a Nakayama algebra with Kupisch series $[c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}]$ and Jacobson radical $J$ (given by quiver and relations). As is well known every indecomposable $A$-module is of the form $e_i A/e_i J^k$ for $i=0,1,...,n-1$ and $1 \leq k \leq c_i$ (where for $k=c_i$ the module is projective).

Now there is a nice interpretation of $Hom_A(e_i A/e_i J^k, e_s A / e_s J^t)$, namely this is isomorphic to $(e_s J^{max(0,t-k)}/e_sJ^t) e_i$, which shows that a basis is given by paths starting at $s$ in the quiver and ending at $i$ of length at least $max(0,t-k)$ and strictly smaller than $t$.

> Question: Is there a similar nice (combinatorial) interpretation for the stable Hom? That is $\underline{Hom}_A(e_i A/e_i J^k, e_s A / e_s J^t)$ .

Here is the ugly result I got for the vector space dimension (using the Auslander-Reiten formulas):

$dim \underline{Hom}_A(e_i A/e_i J^k, e_s A / e_s J^t)= dim( (e_{i+1} J^{max(0,k-t)} / e_{i+1} J^k)e_s) + dim ( (e_{i+1} J^{max(0,k-c_s+t)}/e_{i+1} J^k) e_{s+t} - \dim((e_{i+1}A/e_{i+1}J^k)e_s).$

for $k<c_i$ and $t < c_s$.